# Searching an array and filtering it Angular

Tags: angular

I am implementing search functionality in Angular.
I am displaying details from an array into a div.
What I want is to display only those details whose name I type in searchbox.
I am trying filter method on array and this is what I have tried:

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../Employee';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  filteredEmployees:Employee[]=[]

  searchText=""

  employeeList:Employee[]=
  [
    {
    id:1,
    name:"abc def",
    salary:20000,
    permanent:true,
    department:{id:1, name:"Payroll"},
    skill:[{id:1 , value:"HTML"},{id:2 , value:"CSS"},{id:1 , value:"JS"}],
    dateOfBirth:new Date('01/03/2002')
    },
    {
    id:1,
    name:"ssss gggg",
    salary:40000,
    permanent:false,
    department:{id:2, name:"Internal"},
    skill:[{id:1 , value:"HTML"},{id:2 , value:"CSS"},{id:1 , value:"JS"}],
    dateOfBirth:new Date('21/03/2006')
    },
    {
    id:1,
    name:"asdf zxcv",
    salary:60000,
    permanent:true,
    department:{id:3, name:"HR"},
    skill:[{id:1 , value:"HTML"},{id:2 , value:"CSS"},{id:1 , value:"JS"}],
    dateOfBirth:new Date('16/05/2010')
    }
  ];

  searchKey(data:string)
  {
    this.searchText=data;
  }

  search()
  {
    this.filteredEmployees = this.employeeList.filter((element)=>{
      return element.name.toLowerCase()==this.searchText.toLowerCase();
    });
  }

}
```

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <b>Employees List</b>
    <br>
    <br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="search">Search</label>
                <input type="text" (keyup)="search()" id="search" [(ngModel)]="searchKey(searchText)"  placeholder="Find by name" ngModel>
            </div>

    <div class="row" *ngFor="let e of employeeList">
        <div class="block" style="width:300px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;">
            <h4>{{e.name}}</h4>
            <h6>₹ {{e.salary}}</h6>
            <app-employee-info></app-employee-info>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to two way bind `searchKey` with search text box and its keyup event should call the `search` function.
search then filters based on the input.
But I get this error :
`Unexpected token '=' at column 22 in [searchKey(searchText)=$event]`

Also one more thing ::How do I connect my display div to my search box so that it only displays based on the filtered results??

Comment: In your input `[(ngModel)]="searchText"`  or `[ngModel]="searchText"  (ngModelChange)="searchKey($event)"`?

Comment: @Kitsune66 got it, thanks a lot

Comment: good. Also, if you use ngModelChange you can remove (keyUp) and in the searchKey method just call search after updating current search value. `  searchKey(data: string) {
    this.searchText = data;
    this.search();
  }`

Comment: `<div class="row" *ngFor="let e of filteredEmployees">` to show filtered employees. And update search method to return all employees if search is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

full solution from comments.

Update input and *ngFor

```
  <input type="text" id="search" [ngModel]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="searchKey($event)" placeholder="Find by name"
    ngModel>

........

<div class="row" *ngFor="let e of filteredEmployees">
```

Update ts file

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.search();
  }


  searchKey(data: string) {
    this.searchText = data;
    this.search();
  }

  search() {
    this.filteredEmployees = this.searchText === ""? this.employeeList : this.employeeList.filter((element) => {
      return element.name.toLowerCase() == this.searchText.toLowerCase();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Man, this works perfectly. Just one tiny issue though.The div is empty unless u search something or type in textbox.Then it displays everything. Why is that??

Comment: Btw , thanks for the help.Really appreciate it.

Comment: sorry for delay @sapter. You need to populate filteredEmployees when component loads. just run the search() method on component init.
  `ngOnInit(): void {
    this.search();
  }`. Updated my answer.

Comment: np , I figured it out. Appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a very simple procedure for this.
on your **Search()** clone the employee to other array.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cEmployee = this.employeeList;
  }

  search() {
    var x = [];

    if (this.searchText == '') {
      this.employeeList = this.cEmployees;
    } else {
      this.filteredEmployees = this.employeeList.filter((element) => {
        element.name.toLowerCase() == this.searchText.toLowerCase();
      });

      this.employeeList = this.filteredEmployees;
    }
  }
```

Comment: unused variable 'x' :)

Comment: @saper should use filteredEmployees in the template. No need to "clone" employeeList.

Comment: what does x store?

Comment: it's a typo, ignore it

Comment: Hey  @sapter. cloning is the best way to do it. cause it wont change the original array and if user clears the search text the div will display all elements.

Comment: There's no need to change the html.